# How to implement multiple jquery formBuilder in loop?

Tags: jquery, formbuilder

I want to create multiple formBuilder in a for loop using this library [formBuilder](https://formbuilder.online/).

Here is the code I'm using

```php
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { ?>
<div id="fb-editor-<?php echo $i; ?>"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

And in jquery

```
var fbs = [];
var options = {
    scrollToFieldOnAdd: false
};
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    fbs.push($('#fb-editor-' + i).formBuilder(options));
}
```

It's working, and all of the formBuilders implemented.
But I can only get the json data of the last formBuilder (not others) using this code: `console.log(fbs[4].actions.getData())`, And the other formBuilders return the data in promise and I don't know how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

"You can try it like this, Init by Recursive Function."

codepen.io/chiahungwang/pen/PoYrMEZ?editors=1010

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).